# jQuery autodetect input state

Tags: jquery, search, hide

I'm trying to make a div apear and disapear when typing in a regular input box. It should toggle to be visible only when the input has content, without having a button or an action outside the input box.

I've tried several options. When using .change it only updates the state of the div when I click the mouse outside of the input.

If I am using .val() == '' and .addClass if empty it does not toggle the state of the class when the value change.

I'll add the latest try I had, with .val(),

```
<div id="bd_search">
  <div class="inner">
    <input class="inptsrch" type="text"  placeholder="Perform your search here.." />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bd_search_res">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="res_col1">
      Results from Category A.
    </div>
       <div class="res_col2">
      Results from Category B.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('input.inptsrch').val() == ''){
    $( "#bd_search_res" ).addClass( "srcresHide" );
    }
});
```

Anybody have experience with this behavior through jquery?

https://jsfiddle.net/johneilif/r4uh3dag/

Comment: by the way, where is `bd_search` defined? What is its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way: https://jsfiddle.net/r4uh3dag/15/

```
$("input.inptsrch").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ''){
        $( "#bd_search_res" ).show();
    }
    else{
        $("#bd_search_res").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like it worked. I dont know why but I thought keyup would call the function even if you were outside of the input area. Thank you very much. I also saw this jQuery plugin that might do the trick as an autocomplete tool. http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` event to check when the user press any key and the input has some value or not (`if else` conditions here do that) and based on the `val()` of the input, if it is empty or not, add or remove the desired class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.inptsrch").keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $( "#bd_search_res" ).addClass( "srcresHide" );
        }
        else{
            $("#bd_search_res").removeClass( "srcresHide" );
        }
    });
});
```